# How to save hidden data to wxGrid cell?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxgrid

I'm trying to create a column where there's a number shown, and after clicking the number, a URL is opened in the browser. Each row in the column will correspond to a different URL. However the URL is too long to display in a cell of its own, as there are a number of other columns to fit, and showing it is just not necessary. What's the best way to invisibly save data (the URL) to a grid cell?

One approach which works is a global variable, just keeping a list of URLs.

Another would be if there was a way to set the URL to the balloon/hover/caption text of individual cells, but I don't think you can set custom ToolTips to cells in wxPython.

Any ideas? Thanks so much.

Comment: are the numbers for each url going to be unique?

Comment: no, they will not be unique.

Comment: each cell should be unique. so dict using the cell position as key to store the url would be easier, i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something along these lines:
Put all the urls in a dict using the numbers displayed in the grid as key.

```
a = {1:'http:\\www.google.com', 2:'http:\\www.twitter.com', 3:....}
```

Bind the selection events to an event handler which fetches the number shown in the selected cell and finds the corresponding url for that number from the dict.